# Packer-build VM does not start: Unable to rename file '(null).new' to '(null)': Bad address

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, qemu, virt-manager, packer

## Setup

### Host

#### OS

Manjaro XFCE x86_64

#### Apps

[packer](https://www.packer.io/) (plugins: qemu)
virt-install
virt-viewer
virt-manager

### Guest

```
OS:                Arch Linux  
Hypervisor:        QEMU KVM  
Architecture:      x64
Machine Type:      qc35
EFI Firmware Code: /usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd
EFI Firmware Vars: /usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd
```

See https://github.com/safenetwork-community/bastille-installer/tree/arch for the box I'm trying to build.

I'm trying to build a vagrant box with Arch Linux OS installed and some app that needs to use partitions, so I can't use docker for this.

I also like using EFI for this, although not really necessary, I'm a perfectionist when it comes to this project of mine.

The last time I worked on this, I took compromises and support dropped for one piece of software making the box permanently outdated.

So I want to do it right this time around and want nothing but the best of everything that I perceive as such.

The problem is with EFI.

After building the box with `packer build` I can't run the box without receiving an error.

*error*

```
Starting install...
ERROR  Unable to rename file '(null).new' to '(null)': Bad address
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
virsh --connect qemu:///system start testvm1
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

This happens when running the command below:

*virt-install command*

```
sudo virt-install \
--name bastille-installer \
--vcpu 2 \
--memory 1024 \
--osinfo archlinux \
--disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/bastille-installer_qemu_archlinux-2023-05.qcow2 \
--import \
--boot loader=/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd,loader.readonly=yes,loader.type=pflash,nvram.template=/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd,loader_secure=no
```

I'm at a loss as to why, what or where a '(null).new'
is being renamed to '(null)'.
Can anyone here help me out with this issue?

[EDIT]
I've discovered I could add a --debug parameter to virt-install.
I slightly altered the --disk option in this run from copy-pasting setups of people with similar issues.

The verbose error looks like so:
https://gist.github.com/Folaht/f5f337449800780c0da1d839171e078d

Comment: The last comma necessary in the -boot line?

Comment: It was missing an option. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have deleted the answer as it is not right.  Why you have only 600 rights?  I see that the user libvirt-qemu owns all the files.  Does it exist?

Comment: It's what happens when you install a VM, (eg. win11) using the GUI of virt-manager. virt-install is the CLI of virt-manager.

Comment: I tried 777 and folaht:folaht. Same error.

Comment: I don't see why you deleted your answer. 
You WERE helping me a lot and it was worth 500 points if we figure out the issue.
I think we're on the right track by looking at the parameters.

Comment: Specifically the nvram parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
`/usr/share/edk2-ovmf` is a symbolic link to
`/usr/share/edk2` and that seems to have thrown off virt-install trying to find the nvram_template file.

This unfortunately brings me back to [my original problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744478/vm-boots-into-uefi-interactive-shell-with-the-filesystem-missing).
So I will just have to ask again, now with extra information.